# will O(n+1) be more accurate than O(n)

Tags: big-o

Given a string of length `n`, I always use an `n+1` length array to do the dynamic programming.

In this case, if I say it is `O(n)` [rather than `O(n+1)`] will it be inaccurate?

Comment: AFAIK, `O(n+1)` is `O(n)`...so most of the time people would just report the latter.

Comment: Why O(n+1) is O(n) theoretically? I looks the other way round, that is O(n) is O(n+1) @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: No, it will be perfectly accurate. `n != n+1`, but `O(n) == O(n+1)`.

Comment: Big-O is about the *limiting* behaviour: what happens for large values of `n`. If `n` is a billion, who cares about +/-1?